# trouble to create a contactform with CakePHP 4

Tags: cakephp, contact-form

I started using cakePHP 4 a while ago and my website is quite done. But i have some trouble creating a contact Form. I did as instructed on the cookbook > Modelless Forms, Validation and Forms but i do not get it right (for me the cookbook is really hard to understand sometimes).

When i press my button to send the form, the same page appears with filled fields but no validation or error messages are shown. I am sure i forgot something to send these information from the controller and something to get these data from the controller but ... i cant find what exactly i need. Also i do not exactly understand what i have to fill in the ContactController "$this->request->is('get')"
i hope someone of you can help me out of there. Maybe i just have a big board in front of my head...

here is my code (the templatecode is just a excerpt)

src/Controller/ContactController.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use App\Form\ContactForm;

class ContactController extends AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $contact = new ContactForm();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($contact->execute($this->request->getData())) {
                $this->Flash->success('We will get back to you soon.');
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error('There was a problem submitting your form.');
                $contact->setErrors(['name' => ['_required' => 'at least 5 signs'],['email' => ['_required' => 'Your email is required']]);
            }
        }

        if ($this->request->is('get')) {
            $contact->setData([
                'name' => 'John Doe',
                'email' => 'john.doe@example.com'
            ]);
        }

        $this->set('contact', $contact);
    }
}
```

src/Form/ContactForm.php

```
<?php
/* https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/form.html */
namespace App\Form;

use Cake\Form\Form;
use Cake\Form\Schema;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class ContactForm extends Form
{
    protected function _buildSchema(Schema $schema): Schema
    {
        return $schema->addField('name', 'string')
            ->addField('email', ['type' => 'string'])
            ->addField('subject', ['type' => 'string'])
            ->addField('message', ['type' => 'text']);
    }

    public function validationDefault(Validator $validator): Validator
    {
        $validator->minLength('name', 5)
            ->email('email')
            ->notEmptyString('subject', 'Please fill this field')
            ->notEmptyString('text', 'Please fill this field')

        return $validator;
    }

    protected function _execute(array $data): bool
    {
        print_r('TESTING OK');
        return true;
    }

    public function setErrors($errors)
    {
        $this->_errors = $errors;
    }
}
```

templates/Pages/contact.php (used with ready HTML Templates for the style)

```
...
<?php echo $this->Form->create($contact); ?>
       <div class="row gtr-50 gtr-uniform">
             <div class="col-6 col-12-mobilep">
             <?php echo $this->Form->control('name',['label' => false,'placeholder'=>$translation['Name'],'templates' => ['inputContainer' => '{{content}}']]);?>
             </div>
       <div class="col-6 col-12-mobilep">
             <?php echo $this->Form->control('email',['label' => false,'placeholder'=>$translation['Email'],'templates' => ['inputContainer' => '{{content}}']]);?>
             </div>
             <div class="col-12">
             <?php echo $this->Form->control('subject',['label' => false,'placeholder'=>$translation['Betreff'],'templates' => ['inputContainer' => '{{content}}']]);?>
             </div>
             <div class="col-12">
             <?php echo $this->Form->textarea('message',['label' => false,'placeholder'=>$translation['Bitte gebe deine Nachricht ein'],'rows'=>'6']); ?>
             </div>
             <div class="col-12">
             <ul class="actions special">
             <li><?php echo $this->Form->submit($translation['Nachricht senden']); ?></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
...
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: After your success message, you don't redirect anywhere, so it's to be expected that it will just reload the same page.

Comment: For that controller and action your template would need to be in `templates/Contact/index.php`. Seeing that template in `Pages` I'd furthermore assume that you're not using the correct URL, which by default (eg using the default app template's routes config) would be `/contact`.

Comment: i do not get any message. the form is not checked anyway. i can fill the form with just dashes and i come back to the form

Comment: ah, well here could be the problem yes - i will try tomorrow -  at moment i have this in my routes.php for my contact form: $routes->connect('/contact', ['controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'contact']);

Comment: indeed, this fixed my problem. i didnt even think about the possibility to move the contact form and reconfigure the routes.php. It is working like a charm right now. Best, Thank you! i do not need a redirect, cause i throw a message in the same window and block the "send message" button for this pageload. So Thank you both for the support!